# Show Redcloth source in ckeditor : rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I just installed ckeditor into my rails app. Now i am trying to do is, configure redcloth and ckeditor in a way that, instead of the html source i would like the ckeditor to show the redcloth source ?

Any hints on how would i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CKEditor just for its toolbar, I mean just just the possibility to be able to use buttons to apply formatting, I think you should not use CKEditor, which is (from what I know) absolutely not made to work with markdown. What you are looking is a markdown editor.

I recently looked for a good markdown editor, and guess what, the best solution I have found is Stackoverflow markdown editor. It is called [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)

Note that this editor is a lot lighter than something like ckeditor since the actual element in which you are editing your content is just a textarea. You just hook pagedown to it by using javascript. In Ckeditor, you are actually writing your content into an iframe with a `contentEditable="true"` parameter, and CKEditor is recopying what you are writing into a hidden textarea.

Comment: cool thanks. but i am looking for something that has a WYSIWYG editor and a markup formatting hoke together, which outputs into html

Comment: thank you :D. i had no idea about that. but i am still looking for something the way mediawiki does. wysiwyg and when clicked on source, it shows the markup formatting/source.